# How to chain multiple javascript `scroll()`?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a page and script like this:

**Desired behavior:**

I want to scroll to each `listitem` pause for a sec then scroll to next `listitem` and continue till the end of the list.

**The shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem:**

My attempted code looks like this:

```js
const sleep = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time, "done sleeping"));


let elm = document.querySelector('#pane-side');
let listitems = elm.children[0].children[0].children
for (let index = 0; index < listitems.length; index++) {
  const y = listitems[index].getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
  elm.scroll({
    top: y,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  sleep(1000).then(msg => console.log(msg));
}
```

```html
<div id="pane-side">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
        <div role="listitem"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**A specific problem or error:**

It only scrolls once to the first `listitem` and then does nothing.

**Debugging attempts:**

Another variant that I tried was replacing

`elm.scroll({..})`

with

`listitems[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });`

which didn't even scroll once.

Comment: All 4 sections as asked have been added:

1) **Desired behavior:**

2) **The shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem:**

3) **A specific problem or error:**

4) **Debugging attempts:**

Comment: So do any of the answers help you?

Comment: @mplungjan yes they do, but the fact that new answers cant be posted doesn't help.

Comment: It is now open for new answers. Not sure what you are missing from the ones given so far

Answer (score 3):

You need some more CSS to do this

And why not use interval?

Here is a version that uses your original scroll and does not move the page. I had to tweak the offsetTop to handle margins and padding

Change the counting to

const listItem = listitems[cnt % len];

and add cnt++ to the end of the function to loop around

```js
let cnt = 0, tId;
const elm = document.querySelector('#pane-side');
const listitems = elm.querySelectorAll("[role=listitem]");
const len = listitems.length;

const scrollDiv = () => {
  const listItem = listitems[cnt];
  const topPosition = listItem.offsetTop-7; // adjusted for padding/margin
  elm.scroll({
    top: topPosition,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  cnt++;
  // stop at the end
  if (cnt >= listitems.length) {
    clearInterval(tId);
    return; 
  }


};
scrollDiv(); // start
tId = setInterval(scrollDiv, 1000)
```

```css
#pane-side {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: scroll
}

[role=listitem] {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="pane-side">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div role="listitem">1</div>
        <div role="listitem">2</div>
        <div role="listitem">3</div>
        <div role="listitem">4</div>
        <div role="listitem">5</div>
        <div role="listitem">6</div>
        <div role="listitem">7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you doing this `if (cnt >= listitems.length) cnt = 0;`?  I dont need it to be infinite.

Comment: So remove it...

Comment: simply removing will throw overflow error, my point was if I return from there will not nearly blank scrollDiv() functions with one only line to execute get queued infinitely ?

Comment: Have a look now. You need to tweak the height of the page since right now, the scroller stops without the last pane in view because the page here is longer than  the panes. On a full screen it will work better or if you have a padding on the last div

Comment: you didn't answer my previous question, what is the harm in returning from there, I wanted to understand that clearly first. returning from there instead of resetting it to zero aparently works, but will it hog my browser memory ?

Comment: This isn't working for me. However Reverting `listItem.offsetTop-7;` to `listitems[cnt].getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;` works.

Comment: Ok, fine. Yes you need to do the clearInterval to stop the scroller at end as I added

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use a function which you call recursively via `setTimeout()`, incrementing the index with each call. Note that you can use the modulo operator to make sure the index never goes out of bounds.

```js
let elm = document.querySelector('#pane-side');
let listitems = elm.children[0].children[0].children[0].children;

const scrollToItem = index => {
  listitems[index % listitems.length].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "end",
    inline: "nearest"
  });
  setTimeout(() => scrollToItem(++index), 1000);
}
scrollToItem(0);
```

Here's working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6srbtvjz/.
Note that I had to place it in a jsFiddle as the scrolling caused issues with the SO layout when using a snippet.

Comment: I repeatedly forget the elegance of this `listitems[index % listitems.length]`

Comment: both the answers assumed I want infinite, I should have been more explicit. I can't even think of any infinite use case which to you guys seems to the default.

Comment: We obv could not imagine why you would want to stop ;)

Comment: The general patten for this is to scroll back to the start so that no one can miss a slide; they will come around again. If you want to stop, just don't call `setTimeout()` when `index` is at the max value